# Compiler error in uninstantiated template when a constexpr function calls a non-constexpr one

Tags: templates, c++11, constexpr

In the following piece of C++11 code, the function `get` is `constexpr`
but it tries to construct an instance via the non-`constexpr` constructor.

```
template <typename T>
struct S
{
    S() {}
    static constexpr S get() { return S(); }
};

int main()
{
    // S<int> s1;
    // auto s2 = s1.get();
}
```

While this code compiles with GCC, it fails with the compiler we use at
work with the message

> constexpr function return is non-constant.

We started a discussion whether the compiler is allowed to issue an error in 
this case. I think that the compiler has to accept the code. Otherwise I do
not see how `std::time_point` could work in C++11 because its constructor is 
`constexpr` only since C++14.

So is this a quality-of-implementation thing or does the standard say 
something about uninstantiated templates w.r.t `constexpr`?
Further, would it change anything if the code in the comments were 
activated (i.e. invoking a `constexpr` function on a non-`constexpr` 
object)?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `std::time_point` point you're trying to make? I'm failing to see any problem there. It can work in C++11 simply because nothing needs the `constexpr` constructors?

Comment: @hvd `std::time_point::max` is `constexpr` but its constructor is not (in C++11). In C++14 both are `constexpr`. So this is the same situation as in the code above.

Comment: Ah, right. See [LWG #2054](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2054), that indeed couldn't work in C++11.

Comment: Thanks for the link to LWG #2054! libc++ includes the `constexpr` on the constructor only if compiled in C++14 mode. So I wonder if it is legal that the same header works in C++11 mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is fine:

```
S<int> s1;
```

but the following definition of `get` is ill-formed:

```
static constexpr S get() { return S(); }
```

since it does not return a literal type since `S` does not have a constexpr constructor.

From the draft C++11 standard section `7.1.5` The constexpr specifier [dcl.constexpr]:

> The definition of a constexpr function shall satisfy the following constraints:
>
> - its return type shall be a literal type;

and later on the section it says (*emphasis mine*):

> If the instantiated template specialization of a constexpr function
>   template or member function of a class template would fail to satisfy
>   the requirements for a constexpr function or constexpr constructor,
>   that specialization is not a constexpr function or constexpr
>   constructor. [ Note: If the function is a member function it will
>   still be const as described below. —end note ] **If no specialization
>   of the template would yield a constexpr function or constexpr
>   constructor, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.**

Note in the non-template case both gcc and clang generate an error since the return type is not a literal [see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/apuSJ58BWJbqGbQ1).

Comment: So does this imply that before [LWG #2054](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2054) all compilers would have been required to report an error when `<chrono>` was included?

Comment: @Mehrwolf compilers usually turn off most warnings on system implementation headers [for example gcc uses isystem](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html) and in general the implementation has laxer requirements since the implementers are assumed to know what they are doing.

Comment: @Mehrwolf so I updated my answer, it looks like this particular case does not require a diagnostic.